# Running script after connecting to VPN

Tags: macos, terminal, smb

I am using MacOS 10.12.

I just started working for a company that gave me a VPN connection to connect to.

I'm trying to come up with a script that, upon VPN connection, will:

1. add route to remote VPN subnet
2. mount NAS share via SMB

Also, if possible this script would execute automatically when I connect to VPN. That part would be convenient but that's over my head.

My simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
   #add route to remote subnet
sudo route add –net 192.168.200.0/24 –interface ppp0
   #connect to remote NAS share as currnt user
mount -t smbfs //192.168.200.10/Share /mnt/companyname
```

Will this work? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't macOS automatically adjust the routing once the VPN is up? How do you enable the VPN in the first place?